# android shared preferences flexibility

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to read from the SharedPreferences an integer value as string or viceversa?
Like when you save a json value as integer you can read it as a string.
In this way you can avoid to parse the int to string when you need to show it eg in a TextView

Comment: Why don't you wanna convert the integer to a string and then back?

Answer (score 0):

**SharedPreferences** uses xml to store data and the xml file looks exactely like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
  <int name="key1" value="0" />
  <boolean name="key2" value="true" />
  <string name="key3">example String</string>
 </map>
```

So android uses the `key` to find the xml node that has the value and uses the **node type** to verify the value against the request. and throws `ClassCastException` if they didn't match.
in JSON such verification doesn't exist, the parser would try to parse the value and throws a `JSONException` 'if you are using org.json objects'.

but if you want to achieve JSON behavior and still store your data easily, you can wrap it in a JSONObject then serialize it to String and store it. and when retrieve it parse it as JSONObject again and then read the values from it.

Comment: this is a quite smart solution, i think i'm gonna using this approach
thanks

Comment: I very glad for your help, but it's not a solution for read a SharedPreference in a type different from the written one

Answer (score 0):

You can write a helper class which does it for you. For example:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

/** Preferences (prefs) manager. */
public class Prefs
{
    public static final String MUSIC_KEY = "music_key";
    public static final String VOLUME_KEY = "volume_key";
    public static final String USER_ID_KEY = "user_id_key";
    public static final String FIRST_HELP_KEY = "first_help_key";
    public static final String SECOND_HELP_KEY = "second_help_key";
    public static final String CHALLENGE_HELP_KEY = "challenge_help_key";
    public static final String PREMIUM_KEY = "premium_key";
    public static final String GAMES_PLAYED_WHEN_STATS_SENT_KEY = "stats_games_played_key";

    private static final String FILENAME = "preferences";
    private static final SharedPreferences prefs = Const.context.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    public static boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue)
    {
        return prefs.getBoolean(key, defValue);
    }

    public static float getFloat(String key, float defValue)
    {
        return prefs.getFloat(key, defValue);
    }

    public static int getInt(String key, int defValue)
    {
        return prefs.getInt(key, defValue);
    }

    public static long getLong(String key, long defValue)
    {
        return prefs.getLong(key, defValue);
    }

    public static String getString(String key, String defValue)
    {
        return prefs.getString(key, defValue);
    }

    public static void putObject(String key, Object value)
    {
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        if (value instanceof Boolean)
        {
            editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Float)
        {
            editor.putFloat(key, (Float) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Integer)
        {
            editor.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Long)
        {
            editor.putLong(key, (Long) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof String)
        {
            editor.putString(key, (String) value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(value + " can't be inserted into SharedPreferences");
        }
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Later, when you want to read an integer value, you can just do:

```
final int lastSentGamesCounter = Prefs.getInt(Prefs.GAMES_PLAYED_WHEN_STATS_SENT_KEY, 0);
```

Writing:

```
Prefs.putObject(Prefs.GAMES_PLAYED_WHEN_STATS_SENT_KEY, 10);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but this way a value saved as integer can not never be read as string. the motivation of this question is that i wrote an application witch read and write values from/to json, but now i have to change it to use SharedPreferences. The problem is that as the app is writen I read values depending on the need. Now if i don't find a solution I have to make changes all around the code (thousands of lines) to read values according to the way they was saved.